# How to use ion_aut library in codeigniter with MY_Controller

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter-2, ion-auth

Hi all i'm searching for a usage of IonAuth library for Codeigniter 2.x and i'm curious to learn how it works.

Downloading the package i have a controller auth.php.
i had a look at this http://blog.nexico.net/article/secure-area-codeigniter-framework-and-ion-auth

So i create, in the core folder of CI, a MY_Controller. 
But how can i use it?

Answer (score 2):

Working with ion_auth.php library is pretty easy. You need to follow these steps.
I assume you have followed ion_auth installation process.

First you need to create a MY_Controller class and put it in core

```
Class MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) 
        {
            redirect(site_url('auth/login'));
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you autoload the ion_auth library.
The second important thing is that you need to extend your every controller with MY_Controller.
(Note : if you dont want to extend with MY_Controller but want to use simple controllers that extend CI_Controller put the above condition in every controller's constructor)
If user is not logged in and try to access any page he will be redirected to auth/login.

Another useful function is here.

```
$user   =    $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
```

This will return the logged in user information.

Hope that's all you need.

Comment: @ocrama you should accept the answer by checking on check sign